# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined ionic 4

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

Seems to be working fine in ionic 3 but throws the above error in ionic 4.
Below are the codes and will really appreciate it if anyone can help solve this issue because i have been stalked for hours trying to resolve the issue.

**profile.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {

  public userProfile: firebase.database.Reference;

   constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;


        this.id = this.user.uid;

        this.userProfile = firebase.database().ref(`driverProfile/${user.uid}/userInfo`);

        });     
}


     getUserProfile(): firebase.database.Reference {
       return this.userProfile;



 }
```

**home.ts**

```
constructor(public ph: ProfileService) {
     this.ph.getUserProfile().on('value', userProfileSnapshot => {
        if (userProfileSnapshot.val() != null) {
          this.earnings = userProfileSnapshot.val().refEarnings;
          this.randomCode = userProfileSnapshot.val().id;
          console.log(this.randomCode);
        } else {
          this.earnings = 0;
        }

        this.pop.hideLoader();
      });
```

**home.html**

```
 <div class='bars'>

      <ion-button class="bars-price">
        <ion-icon color='primary' slot="start" name="key"></ion-icon>
        <div id="cash">{{randomCode}}</div>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
 <ion-title class="ion-padding" class="ion-text-center"><strong>Referal Earnings</strong></ion-title>
  <h1 class="ion-text-center">{{settings.appcurrency}} {{earnings}} </h1>
```

Comment: `this.ph.getUserProfile()` returns `undefined`, apparently? The profile service sets `userProfile` 1. asynchrously and 2. conditionally. So if the access is to early, or the `user` is undefined/null it will not be set.

Comment: thanks but everything works fine in ionic 3 but throw the error in ionic 4. Can you tell me what exactly to do?

Comment: Never worked with ionic. Maybe the order of object creation changed in some way.